# Outgoing WSS authorization from WebRequest C#

Tags: c#, authorization, soapui, credentials, wss

i want to build simple application with request and response from server without using SoapUI. I have problem with authorization, when i send request to server the response is
`"<ns2:ErrorMessage>Job error: Request security validation failed.</ns2:ErrorMessage>"`
My authorization in SoapUI is Outgoing WSS:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-something...">
      <wsse:Username>someone</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">***</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">something</wsse:Nonce>
      <wsu:Created>2015-02-11T09:39:28.574Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Trying this way but doesn't work

```
    System.Net.CredentialCache credentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache(); 
    credentialCache.Add(
        new System.Uri("URL"),
        "Basic", 
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","pass") // trying with and without domain
    );
    request.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

How i can do this authorization? Simple networkCredential doesn't work, i can't write in AUTH username, password and domain, i must do it with Outgoing WSS or idk :/

Comment: Someone could help :/?

Comment: Ref. Help me if you could, i was read everything about that problem. Now i try with WSE v3.0 .dll and when i debug app the error is:

WebServiceBindingAttribute is required on proxy classes.
from code
Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol abc = new WebServicesClientProtocol();
Off the serialization in project properties doesn't matter :/